# Efficient way to overwrite matrix rows in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have the following code that overwrites matrix rows and it takes a considerable time for large matrices. Basically, I need the rows where there is a value of i to contain that value, while the rest should remain zeros

Any suggestions on how to perform the same operation in a more efficient way?

```
matr = np.zeros((178858, 400))

for key, index in values.items():
    vect = get_vector(key)
    matr[index] = vect
```

get_vector returns a vector of length 400, given a key.

values is a dictionary containing a key (string) and an index (integer) for that key.

Comment: what does `values` look like (don't post the whole thing, just a few pairs)?

Comment: @FHTMitchell dictionary like this:
{'weekday': 1033,
 'weekdays': 123156,
 'weekend': 776,
 'weekendat': 156361,
 'weekender': 49772,
 'weekends': 59230,
 'weekes': 56379,
 'weeki': 92312,
 'weekley': 59795,
 'weeklong': 18939,
 'weekly': 1932,
 'weeknd': 13483,
 'weeknight': 23431,
 'weekquick': 116531,
 'weeks': 19966,
 'weekslong': 65883,
 'weeldreyer': 136120,
 'weemee': 62687,
 'weemees': 96805,
 'weems': 47923,
 'ween': 110761,
 'weenie': 73326,
 'weenies': 112514,
 'weensy': 174000,
 'weeny': 55138,
 'weep': 9058,
 'weepiness': 136959}. {key:index-for-matrix}

Comment: Ah I see. What is `get_vector` then?

Comment: get_vector is a function that returns a vector of length 400, given one of the keys above. For example, get_vector('weekday') could return np.array([9, 2, 5, 7, 123, 5...]). How get_vector works is not relevant for the question. If you want to test it, you can put a random number generator there.

Comment: That's ok, I just wanted its return type. My answer should work. Does it run any quicker for you?

Comment: Which is taking the most time - the `get_vector` or the assignment?  As long as `get_vector` has to be called once for each `key` it may be hard to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use advanced numpy indexing which is maybe faster (`values` must be ordered so wont work on python 3.0 - 3.5)

```
indices = np.fromiter(values.values(), dtype=int, count=len(values))
keys = np.array([get_vector(v) for v in values.keys()])

matr[indices] = keys
```